# Why does my import file not work?

Tags: java, import

I am trying to make my file ClickingButtons.java to work, but I am getting an error that it cant find the symbols playerHasItem & freeSlots. Now I tried importing my ItemAssistant.java file, which has the public ints playerHasItem & freeSlots, but after saving and compiling it is still giving me the same errors! :(

This is my import statement in ClickingButtons.java:

```
import server.model.items.ItemAssistant;
```

And these are the public ints in my ItemAssistant:

```
    public int freeSlots()
{
    int freeS = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < c.playerItems.length; i++){
        if (c.playerItems[i] <= 0){
            freeS++;
        }
    }
    return freeS;
}

    public boolean playerHasItem(int itemID, int amt, int slot) {
    itemID++;
    int found = 0;
    if (c.playerItems[slot] == (itemID)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < c.playerItems.length; i++)  {
            if (c.playerItems[i] == itemID)  {
                if(c.playerItemsN[i] >= amt) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    found++;
                }
            }
        }
        if(found >= amt) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
public boolean playerHasItem(int itemID, int amt) {
    itemID++;
    int found = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < c.playerItems.length; i++) {
        if (c.playerItems[i] == itemID) {
            if(c.playerItemsN[i] >= amt){
                return true;
            } else{
                found++;
            }
        }
    }
        if(found >= amt) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

The code that calls fo these ints:

```
if (c.dialogueAction == 717) 
            {
                if (freeSlots() > 0)
                {
                    if (c.tempRune == 1)//air
                    {
                        if (c.omniQuest == 2)
                        {
                            if (c.getItems().playerHasItems(995,10000) && c.getItems().playerHasItems(556,10))
                                {
                                    c.getItems().deleteItems(995,10000);
                                    c.getItems().deleteItems(556,10);
                                    c.getItems().addItems(13599, 1);
                                    c.getDH().sendDialogues(749,57);
                                } else 
                                if (!c.getItems().playerHasItems(995,10000))
                                {
                                    c.getDH().sendDialogues(750, 57);
                                } else
                                if (!c.getItems().playerHasItems(556,10))
                                {
                                    c.getDH().sendDialogues(751, 57);
                                }
                        } else 
                        if (c.getItems().playerHasItems(995,20000) && c.getItems().playerHasItems(556,20))
                        {
                            c.getItems().deleteItems(995,20000);
                            c.getItems().deleteItems(556,20);
                            c.getItems().addItems(13599, 1);
                            c.getDH().sendDialogues(749,57);
                        } else
                        if (!c.getItems().playerHasItems(995,20000))
                        {
                            c.getDH().sendDialogues(750, 57);
                        } else
                        if (!c.getItems().playerHasItems(556,20))
                        {
                            c.getDH().sendDialogues(751, 57);
                        }
                    } else
                    if (c.tempRune == 6)//body
                    {
                        if (c.omniQuest == 2)
                        {
                            if (c.getItems().playerHasItems(995,10000) && c.getItems().playerHasItems(559,10))
                                {
                                    c.getItems().deleteItems(995,10000);
                                    c.getItems().deleteItems(559,10);
                                    c.getItems().addItems(13604, 1);
                                    c.getDH().sendDialogues(749,57);
                                } else 
                                if (!c.getItems().playerHasItems(995,10000))
                                {
                                    c.getDH().sendDialogues(750, 57);
                                } else
                                if (!c.getItems().playerHasItems(559,10))
                                {
                                    c.getDH().sendDialogues(751, 57);
                                }
                        } else 
                        if (c.getItems().playerHasItems(995,20000) && c.getItems().playerHasItems(559,20))
                        {
                            c.getItems().deleteItems(995,20000);
                            c.getItems().deleteItems(559,20);
                            c.getItems().addItems(13604, 1);
                            c.getDH().sendDialogues(749,57);
                        } else
                        if (!c.getItems().playerHasItems(995,20000))
                        {
                            c.getDH().sendDialogues(750, 57);
                        } else
                        if (!c.getItems().playerHasItems(559,20))
                        {
                            c.getDH().sendDialogues(751, 57);
                        }
                    } else
                    if (c.tempRune == 13)//astral 
                    {
                        if (c.omniQuest == 2)
                        {
                            if (c.getItems().playerHasItems(995,10000) && c.getItems().playerHasItems(9075,10))
                                {
                                    c.getItems().deleteItems(995,10000);
                                    c.getItems().deleteItems(9075,10);
                                    c.getItems().addItems(13611, 1);
                                    c.getDH().sendDialogues(749,57);
                                } else 
                                if (!c.getItems().playerHasItems(995,10000))
                                {
                                    c.getDH().sendDialogues(750, 57);
                                } else
                                if (!c.getItems().playerHasItems(9075,10))
                                {
                                    c.getDH().sendDialogues(751, 57);
                                }
                        } else 
                        if (c.getItems().playerHasItems(995,20000) && c.getItems().playerHasItems(9075,20))
                        {
                            c.getItems().deleteItems(995,20000);
                            c.getItems().deleteItems(9075,20);
                            c.getItems().addItems(13611, 1);
                            c.getDH().sendDialogues(749,57);
                        } else 
                        if (!c.getItems().playerHasItems(995,20000))
                        {
                            c.getDH().sendDialogues(750, 57);
                        } else
                        if (!c.getItems().playerHasItems(9075,20))
                        {
                            c.getDH().sendDialogues(751, 57);
                        }
                    }
                } else
                {
                    c.getDH().sendDialogues(752, 57);
                    c.tempRune = 0;
                }
            }
```

Also, the import directory is correct.

Why oh why is it not working?

Comment: Can you add code where you are trying to call playerHasItem method?

Comment: Java does not have free standing functions

Comment: Could you include the complete declaration of ItemAssistant class?

Comment: I suspect JRL is on the mark - the methods are likely not enclosed in a class body.

Comment: Problem solved, the variables are called playerHasItem, not playerHasItems. Etc. Note the "s" at items.

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration describes method with three `int` parameters:

```
playerHasItem(int itemID, int amt, int slot)
```

yet you are calling it with two:

```
playerHasItems(995,20000)
```

There is simply no method with two parameters declared.

Comment: There is also a method with 2 ints, I added it in the question

Comment: Huh wait, where do I add: ItemAssistant ia = new ItemAssistant();
ia.playerHasItem(itemID, amt, slot);
?

Comment: Never mind, my bad. Could you clarify what `c.getItems()` returns?

Comment: I did find this:

    public ItemAssistant getItems() {
  return itemAssistant;
 }    

Is it related?

Comment: relates too this?:  private ItemAssistant itemAssistant = new ItemAssistant(this);

Also: how do you post code in this?